# Baal Haleshem on Bitachon

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, faith-bitachon-emunah, chazon-ish

I have seen several people mention the position of the R' Shlomo Elyashiv z"l, the "[Baal Haleshem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Elyashiv)", on trust, bitachon. He seems to be one of the main sources for a position different from the famous one of the Chazon Ish in Emunah Uvitachon. See for instance [this article](https://outorah.org/p/114194) for some of the differences.
What is a precise reference to the words of the Baal Haleshem on this topic? Is the source available online?

Comment: This is an excellent question - I also have some questions on that article that I may post soon

Comment: These ideas are not contradictions. The Possuk says, והבוטח בה' חסד יסובבנו. See the Peirush of Rabbeinu Yona to Mishlei 3:26 (brought in Kad Hakemach of R' Bachye) that bitachon has two meanings. The primary one is that everything is directed by Hashem, the secondary one is that therefore there is always hope for the best.

Comment: @N.T. I'm just asking for a reference.

Comment: The Chazon Ish tells you he is responding to Mussar's take on Bitachon. So I personally would have gone to the maamarim on Bitachon in Madreigas haAdam, by the Alter of Novhardok. Although that kind of prescriptive "if you have Bitachon things will work out" approach to Bitachon is pretty fundamental to Chassidus (including Chabad) and is also found in the Beis haLevi's essay on Bitachon. I am trying to decide exactly where the Chovos haLvavos stood -- whether Bitachon is a way of getting Divide Aid for my plans or the path of accepting His Plans.

Comment: @MichaBerger would you say all Chassidus or only some? I know for sure Breslav and Chabad would take that approach. For me its difficult to believe its a universally held position.

Comment: @MichaBerger "Things will work out." As usual, I can't follow these things. Of course "things will work out" - Hashem is running the world, he is כולו חסד, what he does is wonderful! Are they saying that I'll get whatever _I_ believe is best? That seems absurd and surely no one believes that. Aside from that the world doesn't look that way at all, that seems ח"ו to  make me the All-Powerful instead of the Creator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lesham Shevo veAchalma, Seifer HaDa'h cheleq 2, 5:4:3, pg קלה \ 269 col 2 ([available here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37426&st=&pgnum=268), within the last paragraph):

> האמת הוא שאין דבר עומד נגד הביטחון וכמ"ש במדרש תהלים מזמור ל"ב. והבוטח בה' חסד יסובבנו. אפי' רשע הבוטח בה' חסד יסובבנהו. ואמרו שם עוד. רבים מכאובים לרשע לפי שאינו תולה בטחונו בקב"ה והבוטח בה' אפי' רשע כו' ע"ש וכן אמר הרמב"ן בספר האמונה והביטחון פ"א כי זהו שנאמר בטח בה' ועשה טוב ולא אמר עשה טוב ובטח בה' כי הביטחון אינו תלוי במעשים טובים כלל, אלא בטח בה' בין שתהיה צדיק בין שתהיה רשע בטח בה', אלא שאחר כך אמר ועשה טוב כי אם לא כן הרי יפרע ממך עכ"פ, כי הקב"ה מאריך רוחיה וגבי דיליה וימצא עת וזמן לפרע ממך עכ"פ, ואולי גם דברי חובות הלבבות הוא ג"כ רק עד"ז. ע"ש אבל הביטחון עצמו. במה שהוא בוטח. אין דבר עומד לנגדו

Comment: Thank you! But I don't see that this quote goes very far. It just says that even reshaim are eligible for chesed. It doesn't say your very helpful summary "if you have Bitachon things will work out".

Comment: I had heard that the Leshem goes through a list of reasons why the בוטח _doesn't_ get what he trusts in - because otherwise he would have to get it.

Comment: R' Micha, am I guessing right that this is a common issue? I've seen several articles that bring Rishonim like the Chovos Halevovos (or Rashi) as evidence for the ""if you have Bitachon things will work out" system, and usually the Rishonim at least are saying something much fuzzier near as I can tell.

Comment: @MichoelR, R Dr Seth Mandel was niftar this past summer. He was a Rebbe-Chaver who had a PhD in Semitic Languages from Harvard. (And the OU's rav in charge of all shechitah.) Shiv'ah wasn't over before I was wondering if that is what the Chovos haLvavos was really saying. There are a few words in Shaar haBitachon that I wish I could have discussed with someone who knows both hashkafah and Medieval Judeo-Arabic.

Comment: @MichoelR, I also think the fact that the Chazon Osj wrote Emunah uBitachon in 1951 is very significant. So many people with true Emunah and real Bitachon had just been slaughtered.... The prescriptive "Bitachon earns positive outcomes" wasn't a derekh for the people of that time and place. (And it is a bit difficult in 5784, too.)

Comment: R' Micha, I have always had trouble following this. You don't need six million deaths to notice that Hashem runs the world, not our wishes. Why don't the greatest tzaddikim just take care of all problems with bitachon? In the end everyone needs to provide enough exceptions that Hashem is the one running the world.

Comment: Ah - I see the part I was wondering about, third paragraph in siman ד. "And do not wonder about many great early holy ones who suffered many difficulties: Why did they not use the midah of bitachon, and they certainly would have been saved?..." See there. That question seems quite inconsistent with the approach of the Chazon Ish.

Comment: @MichoelR, I think you are thinking too logically. Yes, logically, the problem tzadiq vera lo is the same either way. But answers that you can swallow when it is on a normal scale feel cold and/or intellectually dishonest when you think in this context. The Chazon Ish's position predates him. (In fact, I increasingly think the Chovos haLvavos was on that page.) But there was a sudden need to hear it, one that motivates his putting pen to paper.

Comment: R' Micha, I imagine the whole Emunah uVitachon was like that. It seems to me like the sefer was supposed to be a corrective for various ways that the mussar movement was going (in his opinion) too far.

Comment: I wonder if this should be a separate question. According to that Baal Haleshem, there are _three_ reasons why tzaddikim have tzaros: 1) sometimes they want them, 2) sometimes they don't want to bother Hashem to remove them, and 3) sometimes Hashem makes a gezeirah to remove their ability to use their bitachon this way. - It seems a remarkable list. Which of these explains why everyone gets old and dies? Or why Mashiach still hasn't come? Or is it taken for granted that tzaddikim don't/can't use their bitachon to change some parts of Hashem's arrangement of the world? Do we know which parts?

Comment: I know the CI says "Mussar" but the position he pushes back against is specific to Novhardok - and most Chassidim. R Dessler (a scion of Kelm) has a third position. And my bet is Slabodka had yet another, but I don't own Or haTzafun to build a first-hand opinion.

Comment: R' Micha, do you have references on each of _those_?